# Laravel-Backpack/Settings table field in settings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

Is it possible to use the table settings? I was able to add a table field, but after pressing the Add Value and Trash nothing happens. Save button saves NULL in column value in database.

field in settings table:

```
{ "name":"value", "label":"Value", "type":"table", "columns":{"name":"Name", "desc":"Desc", "price":"Price"}, "max":"5", "min":"0" }
```

and with entity_singular:

```
{ "name":"value", "label":"Value", "type":"table", "entity_singular":"price", "columns":{"name":"Name", "desc":"Desc", "price":"Price"}, "max":"5", "min":"0" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me perfectly in the latest Backpack. You could try:

1) checking if there are any javascript errors on page (that stop the table from working properly);

2) a `composer update` to get the latest version;

Comment: 1) I have only one error:

    http://localhost:8000/vendor/adminlte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

2) nothing has changed

I guess that some asset isn't loaded at all.
Perhaps, important is that I upgraded laravel from 5.2 and backpack.

Comment: Ok. That error has nothing to do with it, you're right. Can you try a ```composer update```? The table field functionality has had some fixes pushed in the past 2 weeks.

Comment: composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader

Comment: As I mentioned before [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39944912/laravel-backpack-settings-table-field-in-settings/39951837#comment67212729_39951837) nothing has changed

Comment: Ok, if you have published and/or overwritten the CRUD blade files you might need to pull those in again from the package, as explained here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/172#issuecomment-252546743

Comment: Manually update : resources/view/vendor/backpack/crud/create.blade.php
resources/view/vendor/backpack/crud/edit.blade.php
resources/view/vendor/backpack/crud/form_content.blade.php
resources/view/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/table.blade.php